# What's the Best Way to Schedule and Manage Multiple Processes in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project in Python 3 that involves reading lines from a text file, manipulating those lines in some way, and then writing the results of said manipulation into another text file. Implementing that flow in a serial way is trivial.

However, running every step serially takes a long time (I'm working on text files that are several hundred megabytes/several gigabytes in size). I thought about breaking up the process into multiple, actual system processes. Based on the recommended best practices, I'm going to use Python's `multiprocessing` library.

Ideally, there should be one and only one `Process` to read from and write to the text files. The manipulation part, however, is where I'm running into issues.

When the "reader process" reads a line from the initial text file, it places that line in a `Queue`. The "manipulation processes" then pull from that line from the `Queue`, do their thing, then put the result into yet another `Queue`, which the "writer process" then takes and writes to another text file. As it stands right now, the manipulation processes simply check to see if the "reader `Queue`" has data in it, and if it does, they `get()` the data from the `Queue` and do their thing. However, those processes may be running before the reader process runs, thus causing the program to stall.

What, in your opinions, would be the "Best Way" to schedule the processes in such a way so the manipulation processes won't run until the reader process has put data into the `Queue`, and vice-versa with the writer process? I considered firing off custom signals, but I'm not sure if that's the most appropriate way forward. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would separate the tasks of dividing your file into tractable chunks and the compute-intensive manipulation part. If that is not possible (for example, if lines are not independent for some reason), then you might have to do a purely serial implementation anyway.

Once you have N chunks in separate files, you can just start your serial manipulation script N times, for each chunk. Afterwards, combine the output back into one file. If you do it it this way, no queue is needed and you will save yourself some work.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a task queue. Celery is a task queue: http://www.celeryproject.org/